# Can anyone identify the regiment and rank from this photograph?

Tags: military, india, identification, uniform

Can anyone identify the regiment this officer belongs to and his rank please? He seems to be wearing an Indian General service medal (1895-1902 pattern) with a battle clasp, but I cannot make out the theatre of engagement written on it (no point guessing as there were 7 battles/expeditions assigned to this medal).

The button design reminds me of the ones issued to the Medical Corps but that is only a guess.

The photographer is T Winter of Murree and Pindee, and dates from the mid to late 1890's[image].

Additional reference images from the same studio, as per the comment below by OP.

1. [image]
2. [image]

Comment: Do we know the officer? The British Gazette might then enable determining which awards the officer received and when.

Comment: Unfortunately no - I got the photo in a box of 19th century photos I bought in a yard sale. There is an almost undecipherable pencil annotation on the back which looks like Williams but I am not certain.

Comment: Here are some related photos from the same studio: https://www.sportscards.com/item/victorian-cabinet-card-military-india-t-winter-murree-and-pindee-collection/142895751404/

Comment: Have you tried consulting relevant sites, such as [Uniformology](http://www.uniformology.com) or [Weapons and Warfare](http://weaponsandwarfare.com) ?